# Reading and writing multiple files with same file extension

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script

I have three different file sets say 10234.su, 10234.ph and 10234.th. I have a shell script using which I can extract some data from 10234.su and can write to 10234.ph and 10234.th, but it works for only one file at a time. I need a modification which can automatically read the files one by one (xxx.su) and write appropriately (xxx.ph and xxx.th). All the three files have always the same names. Exapmle - 10234.su, 10238.su, 10242.su etc. I have a lot of .su files with different names which I want to read one by automatically.

My script is as follows -

```
rm hdrfile binary 

for i in *.su; do 
sugethw <"$i" output=geom key=cdp >hdrfile
a2b <hdrfile n1=994 >binary
echo "$i -> sugethw <"$i" output=geom key=cdp >hdrfile a2b <hdrfile n1=994 >binary"

for j in *.ph; do 
sushw <"$j" infile=binary key=cdp >test1.su
rm "$j"
mv test.su "$j"
echo "$j -> sushw <"$j" infile=binary key=cdp >test.su rm "$j" mv test.su "$j""

for k in *.th; do
sushw <"$k" infile=binary key=cdp >test2.su
rm "$k"
mv test.su "$k"
echo "$k -> sushw <"$k" infile=binary key=cdp >test.su rm "$k" mv test.su "$k""

rm hdrfile binary
done
done
done
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try the following bash shellscript.

After testing, that it acts on all files, you must remove my `echo` lines and the `cp` lines and uncomment your real action lines with `sugethw`, `a2b` and `sushw`.

I don't think you need to remove the files before moving, because `mv` will overwrite unless you use `mv -i`.

```
#!/bin/bash

for filnam in *.su
do
 tmp=${filnam%%.su}
 i="$filnam"
 j="${tmp}.ph"  # guessing they need not be nested
 k="${tmp}.th"  # guessing they need not be nested

 echo "$tmp.hdr" > hdrfile  # replacing lines with commands unknown to me
 echo "$tmp.bin" > binary   # replacing lines with commands unknown to me
 #sugethw <"$i" output=geom key=cdp >hdrfile
 #a2b <hdrfile n1=994 >binary
 echo "$i -> sugethw <\"$i\" output=geom key=cdp >hdrfile a2b <hdrfile n1=994 >binary"

 cp binary test1.su  # replacing line with command unknown to me
 #sushw <"$j" infile=binary key=cdp >test1.su
 #rm "$j"
 mv test1.su "$j"
 echo "$j -> sushw <\"$j\" infile=binary key=cdp >test.su rm \"$j\" mv test.su \"$j\""

 cp binary test2.su  # replacing line with command unknown to me
 #sushw <"$k" infile=binary key=cdp >test2.su
 #rm "$k"
 mv test2.su "$k"
 echo "$k -> sushw <\"$k\" infile=binary key=cdp >test.su rm \"$k\" mv test.su \"$k\""
 echo "---"
done 

rm hdrfile binary
```

Comment: It worked very well. Thank you very much for your quick reply!!

Comment: @BrijBhushanSingh, You are welcome. I am glad that I could help :-)